# In App Purchase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm tearing my hair out, I've wasted a day and a half on this. I thought Swift was supposed to be easier but I find it a nightmare compared to Objective-C. I've been trying to port a project over to swift for a month now and I'm seriously considering scrapping it and just going back to Objective-C. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. I previously used the tutorial on raywenderlich.com which gave a nice reusable IAP class. However when attempting to convert this over to Swift I just keep running into problems I can't find my way around. Some of the errors Xcode give are just utterly pointless in their description and Google is little help.

Firstly is this a suitable translation of code? The Swift guide is no help here :

Objective-C

```
typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);
```

Swift

```
typealias RequestProductsCompletionHandler = (success : Bool, products : NSArray)
```

When I try to act on this later with

```
_completionHandler(true, skProducts)
```

I get the error

> Cannot convert the expression's type '(BooleanLiteralConvertible, [AnyObject]!)' to type 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'

I also have problems with this

```
- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    // Store product identifiers
    _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

    // Check for previously purchased products
    _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
        if (productPurchased) {
            [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
    }

}
return self;
```

}

As this is supposed to be an initialiser I have no idea how to implement it. I had tried to change it to a regular function that I could call after creating the object but even then I run into problems with this

```
for productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers {
        let productPurchased = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(productIdentifier)
        if productPurchased {
            _purchasedProductIdentifiers.addObject(productIdentifier)
        }
    }
```

As it claims that NSSet

> 'NSSet?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Whatever that is supposed to mean. I also get other random errors from this line about sequencing or something.

Basically it seems that too much has change and converting this tutorial code across is just a non starter. Really it would be nice to see a tutorial for this in Swift but Google is not being my friend. I find it hard to believe no example of this exists.

Can anyone help!? Is there a tutorial for this? Preferably one that sets up IAP as a separate reusable class.

Comment: show us what's "skProducts"

Comment: func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        
        let skProducts = response.products
        
        _completionHandler(true, skProducts)

Comment: for 'NSSet?' does not have a member named 'Generator', you need to unwrap _productIdentifiers, so instead of "for productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers" you need to user "for productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers!" as _productIdentifiers means a nullable NSSet or NSSet?

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/ivanacostarubio/swift-in-app-purchase-example

Comment: I see that your question hasn't been answered but this tutorial is great for anyone doing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3hJ0rY1NNw

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Swift version of the the raywenderlich.com IAP helper.

Here's how the `RequestProductsCompletionHandler` looks:

```
typealias RequestProductsCompletionHandler = (success: Bool, products: NSArray!) -> ()
```

Here's how the class vars and init looks.

```
class IAPHelper: NSObject,SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest!
    var completionHandler: RequestProductsCompletionHandler!
    var nonConsumableProductIDs: NSMutableSet!
    var purchasedProductIdentifiers: NSMutableSet!

    init(nonConsumableProductIDs: NSMutableSet) {
        super.init()

        // Store non-consumable product identifiers
        self.nonConsumableProductIDs = nonConsumableProductIDs

        // check for perviously purchased products
        purchasedProductIdentifiers = NSMutableSet()
        for item in nonConsumableProductIDs {
           let productIdentifier = item as String
            let productPurcahsed = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(productIdentifier)
            if productPurcahsed {
                println("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
                purchasedProductIdentifiers.addObject(productIdentifier)
            } else {
                println("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
            }
        }

        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    }
```

Here's how I'm calling it in my subclass:

```
let nonConsumableProductIDs = NSMutableSet(objects: "com.mainstreetcodellc.Smoothie.removeAds") // non-consumable products
private let _SmoothieIAPHelperSharedInstance = SmoothieIAPHelper(nonConsumableProductIDs: nonConsumableProductIDs)

class SmoothieIAPHelper: IAPHelper {

    class var sharedInstance: SmoothieIAPHelper {
        return _SmoothieIAPHelperSharedInstance
    }
}
```

I'm reluctant to post the rest of my code, because there's a lot of it and I don't remember what I've added since I first went through the raywenderlich tutorial.  I'd be more than happy to post more snippets though, if there's specific sections giving you trouble.  What I've posted so far should answer your question though.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the middle of creating an open source framework with a bud:

https://github.com/Thinkful/iTipJarControl

We are only a week in, but you will find working code for purchases in here.

Most relevant file here:

https://github.com/Thinkful/iTipJarControl/commit/9b1cbe5f366e42f4cdecedab5e1764b74226bee0

Let me know if you have problems with it.  It my take another few weeks before it is all pulled together.

```
+
+import UIKit
+import StoreKit
+
+class iTabJarViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate  {
+
+  var product_value = ""
+
+
+
+  func fetchAvailableProducts() {
+    var productID:NSMutableSet = NSMutableSet();
+    for tag in 1...3 {
+      println("productID: \(iTipJarConfiguration.storeIdentifer(tag))")
+      productID.addObject(iTipJarConfiguration.storeIdentifer(tag))
+    }
+    let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)
+    productsRequest.delegate = self
+    productsRequest.start()
+  }
+
+  func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
+    var count : Int = response.products.count
+    if (count>0) {
+      var validProducts = response.products
+      var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
+      if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_value) {
+        println(validProduct.localizedTitle)
+
+        println(validProduct.localizedDescription)
+        println(validProduct.price)
+        purchaseMyProduct(validProduct)
+      } else {
+        //println(validProduct.productIdentifier)
+      }
+    } else {
+      println("Nothing found in the store")
+    }
+  }
+
+  func canMakePurchases() -> Bool
+  {
+    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
+  }
+
+
+  func purchaseMyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
+    if (self.canMakePurchases()) {
+      println("Purchases are allowed ...")
+      var payment: SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product)
+      var defaultQueue: SKPaymentQueue  = SKPaymentQueue ()
+
+      defaultQueue.addPayment(payment)
+    } else {
+      println("Purchases are disabled in your device")
+    }
+  }
+
+
+    // MARK: - Actions
+  @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
+    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
+  }
+
+  @IBAction func tipButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
+    product_value = iTipJarConfiguration.storeIdentifer(sender.tag)
+    fetchAvailableProducts()
+
+  }
```